# Python string indices must be integers not str

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code:

```
dbcur.execute('select girismuzik from users where name = ?', [username])
rrf = dbcur.fetchone()
girismuzik = rrf
self.sendData("\x1A" + "\x0C" [girismuzik])
```

But this is error:

```
string indices must be integers not str
```

Comment: where the hell the error is generated? maybe add a stacktrace

Comment: You are making a string-index operation of a constant string with the length 1. *IF* this is what you want to do you can just remove the index-access completely.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to slice a string here:

```
self.sendData("\x1A" + "\x0C" [girismuzik])
```

and `girismuzik` refers to a string value.

Perhaps you forgot a comma?

```
self.sendData("\x1A" + "\x0C", [girismuzik])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell more without the stacktrace and the rest of your code. But,

```
self.sendData("\x1A" + "\x0C" [girismuzik])
```

This is the problem.

Specifically: `"\x0C" [girismuzik]`

What this is, is a string, and then an index. (Since you maybe forgot a `,`). it will translate to `"string"[x]` and if `x` is not an int, its an error.

Answer (score 0):

A `cursor.fetchone()` is likely to return a tuple of one resultant row from your query (with one column in it).

You're probably after something more like:

```
dbcur.execute('select girismuzik from users where name = ?', [username])
rrf = dbcur.fetchone()
girismuzik = rrf[0]
self.sendData("\x1A" + "\x0C" + girismuzik)
```